# Detect calendar event overlap conflicts using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a feature that checks if external events collide with internal events (in a calendar app). The process looks like this:

- My application creates an array of possible events (called `$internalEvents`)
- I source external events from calendars such as Google Calendar, iCloud, etc. (called `$externalEvents`). These are existing events with the type `busy`.
- Now I have to check if there is any kind of conflict regarding internal and external events. I tried something as you can see below but this is by far not correct or bulletproof.

I tried to reduce it to the minimum as much as possible. This is the data input:

```
$internalEvents = array(
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 12:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 13:00:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 12:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 13:30:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 13:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 14:00:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 13:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 14:50:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 14:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 15:00:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 14:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 15:30:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 15:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 16:00:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 15:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 16:30:00"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 16:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 17:00:00"
    )
);

$externalEvents = array(
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 08:00:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 12:00:00",
        "type" => "busy"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 15:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 16:00:00",
        "type" => "busy"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "03/29/2016 13:30:00",
        "end" => "03/29/2016 14:15:00",
        "type" => "busy"
    )
);
```

Now I try to find any kind of conflict by comparing the internal event to all external events:

```
foreach($internalEvents as $internalEvent) {

    $internalEventStart = new DateTime($internalEvent['start']);
    $internalEventEnd = new DateTime($internalEvent['end']);

    $result = true;

    echo "\nverifying " . $internalEventStart->format('Y-m-d H:i') . " - " . $internalEventEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n";

    foreach($externalEvents as $externalEvent) {
        $externalEventStart = new DateTime($externalEvent['start']);
        $externalEventEnd = new DateTime($externalEvent['end']);

        // check if there are conflicts between internal and external events
        if ($internalEventStart >= $externalEventStart && $internalEventStart <= $externalEventEnd) {
            $result = false;
            echo "   problem 1: event is between busy time: " . "\n";
        }

        if ($internalEventStart >= $externalEventStart && $internalEventStart <= $externalEventEnd && $externalEventEnd <= $internalEventEnd) {
            $result = false;
            echo "   problem 2: event starts during busy time: " . "\n";
        }

        if ($internalEventStart <= $externalEventStart && $externalEventStart <= $internalEventEnd && $internalEventEnd <= $externalEventEnd) {
            $result = false;
            echo "   problem 3: event stops during busy time: " . "\n";
        }

        if (($internalEventStart <= $externalEventStart) && ($externalEventStart <= $externalEventEnd) && ($externalEventEnd <= $internalEventEnd)) {
            $result = false;
            echo "   problem 4: event during busy time: " . "\n";
        }

        if (($internalEventStart <= $internalEventEnd) && ($internalEventEnd <= $externalEventStart) && ($externalEventStart <= $externalEventEnd)) {
            $result = false;
            echo "   problem 5: event during busy time: " . "\n";
        }
    }

    if($result) {
        echo "   result: OK\n";
    } else {
        echo "   result: NOT OK \n";
    }
}
```

I am looking for an algorithm that can find any possible event overlap conflict. Any hint is highly appreciated.

The running code can be found [here](http://ideone.com/1GbokS) (IDEone.com).

Comment: Your actual code works? I have added the hours to output and it seems don't be coherent for me. Check my result on this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LHiFMz9z): I have marked with `≈` ambiguous results and with `≠` not correct results. Instead, if the result if correct, can you better explain the collision criteria? I have intended that there is collision if there is overlapping... Let me know.

Comment: @fusion3k It used to be working with one set of events but when I changed the events I recognized that it actually does not work. That's why I need the community help. Your findings seem to be correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When two events collide? See this schema:

```
                              ----E----                 CS/EE   CE/ES
                        --N--                             <       <
                                        --N--             >       >
                           --C--                          <       >
                                     --C--                <       >
                                --C--                     <       >
                             -----C-----                  <       >
                    ··················································
                    E  = Main Event
                    N  = Not Collide Event
                    C  = Collide Event
                    CS = Compare Event Start
                    EE = Main Event End
                    CE = Compare Event End
                    ES = Main Event Start
```

As you can see, there is collision only when the start of event C is before the end of event E and the end of event E is after the start of event C. Knowing this helps to find an efficient and short method to compare events.

About the code, a preliminary note: you convert the dates in ISO 8601 before comparing it multiple times in your code, so why do not create a function for this?

```
function eventsToDate( $row )
{
    $retval = array( 'start' => date_create( $row['start'] )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'end' => date_create( $row['end'] )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
    $retval['print'] = sprintf( '%s-%s', substr( $retval['start'],-8,5 ), substr( $retval['end'],-8,5 ) );
    return $retval;
}
```

This function returns an associative array with 'start' and 'end' in your format. I have added a third key, 'print', to use during debug. Note that in the print I consider only hours:minutes (all the dates in your array sample are from same day), but the comparison is made on complete dates. You can omit this 'print' key or replace it with preferred output format.

You execute two nested `foreach`, and for each loop recalculate the date format. With your array samples, you call DateTime/DateTime::format 36 times. By creating a temporary array with all converted `$externalEvents`, we can reduce these calls to 12. So, before starting `foreach()` loop, we use `array_map` with above custom function and `$externalEvents` array to create an array with formatted dates:

```
$externalDates = array_map( 'eventsToDate', $externalEvents );
```

Then, we start the main `foreach()` loop on `$internalEvents`:

```
foreach( $internalEvents as $internalEvent )
{
    $internalDates = eventsToDate( $internalEvent );

    echo $internalDates['print'] . PHP_EOL;
    $result = True;
    foreach( $externalDates as $externalDate )
    {
```

At this point, we compare dates. As mentioned above, we compare start with end and end with start. To simplify next comparison, we use `strcmp`, a php function that “returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2, > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal”:

```
        $startCmp = strcmp( $internalDates['start'], $externalDate['end'] );
        $endCmp   = strcmp( $internalDates['end'],   $externalDate['start']   );
```

Now, the comparison:

```
        if( $startCmp<0 && $endCmp>0 )
        {
            $result = False;
            echo "           {$externalDate['print']} COLLIDE\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "           {$externalDate['print']} OK\n";
        }
    }
```

And, finally, we can print the result:

```
    echo "Result: " . ( $result ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . "\n\n";
}
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/541934)**</kbd>

Note: with above comparison, with first `$internalEvent` we obtain following result:

```
12:00-13:00
           08:00-12:00 OK
           15:30-16:00 OK
           13:30-14:15 OK
Result: OK
```

Instead, if you want this result:

```
12:00-13:00
           08:00-12:00 COLLIDE
           15:30-16:00 OK
           13:30-14:15 OK
Result: NOT OK
```

You have to replace above `if` condition with this:

```
         if( $startCmp<=0 && $endCmp>=0 )
```

Above code will work, if you want more details about kind of collision, you can test other combinations of start/end inside `if` condition.

---

**Alternative: Return Colliding Events**

If — instead of printing results — you want catch colliding events, you can replace nested `foreach()` with `array_filter` in this way:

```
$result = array_filter
(
    $externalDates, 
    function( $row ) use( $internalDates )
    {
        $startCmp = strcmp( $internalDates['start'], $row['end'] );
        $endCmp   = strcmp( $internalDates['end'],   $row['start']   );
        return( $startCmp<0 && $endCmp>0 );
    }
);
```

At this point, colliding events are in array `$result`. Obviously, is the array is empty, there are not collisions.

---

- Read more about [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)
- Read more about [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- Read more about [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Thank you very much fusion3k! I need some time to carefully study it but it looks amazing! I'll come back to you