# php - laravel : How to handle time overlapping in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to save two time interval in my database. where it will check the database and if someone already booked that time it won't save the time whereas if it's empty it will save time which user will give as a input.

> Eg. A user want to book the schedule 8:00 to 8:30, while saving into
>   the database it will check in the database whether someone already take
>   that time or not, if it's not then it will save otherwise it won't. Meanwhile
>   user can't give input even in 8:15 also.

How do i solve this overlapping  problem?

here is the controller code I have used, it doesn't running though:

```
 public function postAllocateRoom(Request $request)
    {

            $classRoom = new ClassRoom();  

            $classRoom->department_id=$request->Input(['department_id']);     
            $classRoom->room_id=$request->Input(['room_id']); 
            $classRoom->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']); 
            $classRoom->day_id=$request->Input(['day_id']); 
            $classRoom->start=$request->Input(['start']); 
            $classRoom->end=$request->Input(['end']);  

            $startTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
            $endTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'));

            $classRoomCount = ClassRoom::where(function ($query) {
                     $query->where('start', '>=', $startTime)
                        ->where('end', '<=', $startTime); })->count();

            $messages ="Class Room Already Taken";
            if ($classRoomCount > 0) {
             return redirect('allocateRoomPage',$message);
                    }
            else {
                 $classRoom->save();            
            return redirect('allocateRoomPage'); 
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule for time overlapping is simple (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36204712/3294262) for a complete graphic explanation):

```
start1 < end2   AND   end1 > start2
```

So your query can be:

```
$classRoomCount = ClassRoom::where
(
    function( $query ) use( $startTime, $endTime )
    {
        $query->where( 'start', '<', $endTime )
              ->where( 'end', '>', $startTime); 
    }
)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to be able to have access to `$startTime` and `$endTime` within the query closure you will need to pass them through using the `use` construct i.e.

```
function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime)
```

The following should work to get the correct counts for classrooms booked between certain times:

```
$classRoomCount = ClassRoom::where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {

    $query
        ->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
            $query
                ->where('start', '>=', $startTime)
                ->where('end', '<', $startTime);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
            $query
                ->where('start', '<', $endTime)
                ->where('end', '>=', $endTime);
        });
})->count();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still I can book the classroom in that certain time which are already in db

Comment: No need to say sorry bro, You are only helping so that's great of you. But I don't  getting why with you above code also I can book classroom with the same interval.

Comment: I thought you didn't want to be able to book a class room that has been booked out at time. The above code will check to see if the classroom has been booked out at that time. if it has it will return a count bigger than 1.