# Laravel php Check if the meeting already scheduled

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to have a checking if there is a meeting already created in the same time when the user try to create a new meeting. the new meeting could be create before or after the other meetings (already created).

here is my meetings table:

| meetings |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| start_time |
| end_time |

and here is my code:

```
$start_time = Carbon::parse($request->start_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_time = Carbon::parse($request->start_time)->addMinutes($request->duration)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$check_meeting = Meeting
    ::whereBetween('start_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
    ->orWhereBetween('end_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
    ->first();

if ($check_meeting) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Cant Create meeting, Please choose other time!');
}
```

the code above still allow to create meeting even the same time meeting already created.
Is there any best way to solve my problem?

Apologies for my bad English, Thank you

Comment: try this oce  $check_meeting = Meeting::where(function($q)use($start_time,$end_time){
    $q->whereBetween('start_time', [$start_time,$end_time]);
    $q->orWhereBetween('end_time', [$start_time,$end_time]);
    })->first();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002168/php-laravel-how-to-handle-time-overlapping-in-database/37002416#37002416

Comment: @eizan.is it working

Comment: my problem is solved, refer to the other thread suggest by @Rwd

Comment: okay.np .have a great day